# Regex pattern for finding HTML image tag with src to the internet

Tags: c#, html, regex

I'm having some problems understanding the regex pattern syntax. 
I'm using `Outlook interop` to go through the `HTMLbody` of an email.msg.

I want to remove all the images that has a reference to the internet.
So I'm useing `Regex.Replace` to find all image tags and replacing them with text.

This is what, I've:

`string altText = " <i>*Reference to picture on the internet removed*</i> ";
string b = Regex.Replace(a, @"(<img([^>]+)>)", altText);`

This works, but I want to find the tags that only have `src` from the internet. 
I found this in my google search:

```
string matchString = Regex.Match(a, "<img.+?src=[\"'](.+?)[\"'].*?>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups[1].Value;
```

But it will not help since it looks like all images have a `src` tag. My goal is to write a pattern syntax if possible in `Regex` where i check if the source ( `src` ) starts with http, https or www.

Is there anyone who can help me with this?

Comment: [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) would allow you handle the task in an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to use an HTML parser in order to find your images tag rather than a regex directly. You can then use a Regex in order to check the src attribute if required.

In the meantime, I believe the following regex will produce the results you are expecting:

```
<img.+?src=[\"']((?:https?|www).*)[\"'].*?>
```

Regex Cases: [Regex](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3Cimg.%2B%3Fsrc%3D%5B%5C%22%27%5D%28%28%3F%3Ahttps%3F%7Cwww%29.*%29%5B%5C%22%27%5D.*%3F%3E&i=%3Cimg%20src%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%3Cimg%20src%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%3Cimg%20src%3D%22www.google.com%22%20%2F%3E)

**Edit**
It is to be noted as well that sometimes links can just start by `//`. The following regex should do it:

```
<img.+?src=[\"']((?:https?|www|//).*)[\"'].*?>
```

For a more extensive Regex solution matching URL, please see [What is a good regular expression to match a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url)

Comment: What HTML parser do you recommend?

Comment: Html Agility Pack is what I usually use: https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what i was looking for. I will also check out HTML parser.